# How to increment an alphanumeric string in PHP?

Tags: php, string

There's a string, containing characters `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. This should be 26 * 2 + 10 = 62 possibilities in one character and 62^2 in two. What is the preferred way to increment a value of such a string, so that 'aA', becomes 'aB', etc.? Is there any built-in stuff in PHP, that can help?

I know you can increment a string, but that's only lowercase letters. Essentially, the result should go from 'a' to 'aa' in 61 increments.

Comment: +1, interesting about this question.

Comment: I didn't know PHP did this, but I do now. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php

Comment: What't the desired progression? I mean, `a b c ... x y z A B C ... X Y Z 0 1 2 ... 7 8 9 aa` isn't it, obviously. So which characters vary fastest, and in which order?

Comment: @Daren Chandisingh, the exact type (lowercase first, or uppercase first), doesn't matter. Just want to have it consistent, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The @simshaun dont work for me. I check the documentation and I found [base_convert](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php) that can work for you (on base 35) and a comment of "*francesco[at]paladinux.net*" with a function to work on base65.

so the solution can be:

convert to b10 -> increment +1  -> convert base 65

**EDIT 1**

talking about convert I think to base64 coding so I wrote this 2 funcs using base64 encode/decode numbers.
Unfortunately the charset used is a bit larger: [a-zA-Z0-9/+=], but using an internal function more efficent.

The Zero
0 is "AA=="

```
function nencode($in){
        $res ="";
        while(1){
                $b = $in & 0xff;
                $res = chr($b) . $res;

                if($in > 0xff){
                        $in = $in >> 8;
                } else {
                        break;
                }
        }
        return base64_encode($res);
}

function ndecode($in){

        $rv=0;
        $res =base64_decode($in);
        for($t = 0 ; $t < strlen($res) ; $t++){
                if($t>0){
                        $rv = $rv << 8;
                }
                $c = ord($res{$t});
                $rv |= $c;
        }
        return $rv;
}
```

Comment: You can't `base_convert` with base > 36

Comment: Have you see the francesco[at]paladinux.net post?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how I could have missed that

Comment: @Fluffy NP, I've write 2 funcs using base64

Answer (score 6):

Try this function:

```
<?php
function increment(&$string){
    $last_char=substr($string,-1);
    $rest=substr($string, 0, -1);
    switch ($last_char) {
    case '':
        $next= 'a';
        break;
    case 'z':
        $next= 'A';
        break;
    case 'Z':
        $next= '0';
        break;
    case '9':
        increment($rest);
        $next= 'a';
        break;
    default:
        $next= ++$last_char;
    }
    $string=$rest.$next;
}

    //sample
    $string='a';
    for($i=1;$i<=128;$i++){
        echo $string."<br>";
        increment($string);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: After `a9` it goes to `aaa` rather than `ba`.

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

```
<?php
$str = 'a';
echo ++$str; // b

$str = 'z';
echo ++$str; // aa

$str = 'aA';
echo ++$str; // aB
```

Comment: This is the same as lowercase letters - uppercase ones will stays uppercase.

Comment: So you are looking for a way to go from `zz` to `aA`? Think I'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: Well, if we talk about 1 character string, `$a = 'a'` should become `aa` in 61 increments. Your solution does so in 25.

Comment: Think I understand now. You are simply trying to move to the next permutation given a set of allowable characters - in which case no, there are no built-in functions that will do this for you (that I'm aware of). You would likely need to implement your own algorithm unless one can be found.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this fundamentally does what you're after.

```
<?php

$chars = array('', 
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 
    'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 
    'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',
    '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9');

$increment1 = 0;
$increment2 = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i <= 200; $i++) {
    if ($increment2 === 62) {
        $increment1++;
        $increment2 = 1;
    } else {
        $increment2++;
    }
    echo "{$chars[$increment1]}{$chars[$increment2]} ";
}

/*
Output:
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 aa ab ac ad ae af ag ah ai aj ak al
am an ao ap aq ar as at au av aw ax ay az aA aB aC aD aE 
aF aG aH aI aJ aK aL aM aN aO aP aQ aR aS aT aU aV aW aX 
aY aZ a0 a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9 ba bb bc bd be bf bg 
bh bi bj bk bl bm bn bo bp bq br bs bt bu bv bw bx by bz 
bA bB bC bD bE bF bG bH bI bJ bK bL bM bN bO bP bQ bR bS 
bT bU bV bW bX bY bZ b0 b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6 b7 b8 b9 ca cb 
cc cd ce cf cg ch ci cj ck cl cm cn co
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

I like this one. How to use: 
ClassX::increment('p04E7K', 6);
ClassX::decrement('p04E7K', 6);

Code:

```
class ClassX {
    public static $baseCharacters = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    public static function increment($x, $digits)
    {
        $charList = static::$baseCharacters;

        // completa cadeia de caracteres com o numero de digitos parametrizados
        $x = trim($x);
        if(strlen($x) < $digits) {
            $x = str_pad($x, $digits, substr($charList, 0, 1), STR_PAD_LEFT);
        }

        $result = preg_split("//", $x, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        // percorre a cadeia de caracteres de tras pra frente e incrementa o primeiro caractere possivel
        for ($i = $digits - 1; $i >= 0; --$i)
        {
            $char = $result[$i];
            $currentChar = strpos($charList, $char);
            $nextCharPosition = $currentChar+1;

            if($nextCharPosition < strlen($charList)) {
                $nextChar = substr($charList, $nextCharPosition, 1);

                $result[$i] = $nextChar;
                break;
            }
        }

        return implode('', $result);
    }

    public static function decrement($x, $digits)
    {
        $charList = static::$baseCharacters;

        // completa cadeia de caracteres com o numero de digitos parametrizados
        if(strlen($x) < $digits) {
            $x = str_pad($x, $digits, substr($charList, 0, 1), STR_PAD_LEFT);
        }

        $result = preg_split("//", $x, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        // percorre a cadeia de caracteres de tras pra frente e decrementa o primeiro caractere possivel
        for ($i = $digits - 1; $i >= 0; --$i)
        {
            $char = $result[$i];
            $currentChar = strpos($charList, $char);
            $previousCharPosition = $currentChar-1;

            if($previousCharPosition > -1) {
                $previousChar = substr($charList, $previousCharPosition, 1);

                $result[$i] = $previousChar;

                // define os caracteres apos o decrementado para o ultimo caractere. ex: 3[00] > 2[99]
                for ($j = $i + 1; $j < $digits && $i < $digits - 1; ++$j)
                    $result[$j] = substr($charList, strlen($charList)-1, 1);
                break;
            }
        }

        return implode('', $result);
    }
}
```

Comment: this simply doesn't work.  try it and you'll see once the last digit gets to `Z` it stays there instead of advancing to 0 and incrementing the next digit.

Answer (score 1):

I came to this question as I was looking also for a way to generate auto incrementing alphanumeric unique ID very similar to what we have in mobile money(M-PESA) in Kenya. 
For reference, here is a screenshot showing the transactions [Screenshot showing sample MPESA transactions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMuYC.png)
I'd like to leave it here if anyone is looking also for similar properties: i.e.
- Autoincrement alphanumeric
- All characters in uppercase
- automatic increase of string length once exhausted.
- the increment is from 0 to 9 then A to Z before incrementing the adjacent character of number and is a modification of @phobia82's answer

```
function increment($string){
    $last_char=substr($string,-1);
    $rest=substr($string, 0, -1);
    switch ($last_char) {
        case '':
            $next= 'A';
            break;
        case 'Z':
            $next = '0';
            $unique = increment($rest);
            $rest = $unique;
            break;
        case '9':
            $next= 'A';
            break;
        default:
            $next = ++$last_char;
            break;
    }
    $string=$rest.$next;
    return $string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach.  We iterate backward from the end of the string and increment each character based on `$characters`.  There's no need to split or implode since each character position can be referenced directly by it's index and this is very fast.

This function will loop based on the string length, so if we pass `ZZ` it will then reset back to `00`. If instead you want to continue adding digits so that `ZZ` become `100` you can set `$loop` to `false`:

```
function increment($x, $loop = true) {
    $chars = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $char_count = strlen($chars);
    $c = strlen($x);
    for ($i = $c - 1; $i >= 0; --$i) {
        $pos = strpos($chars, $x[$i]) + 1;
        $pos = $pos < $char_count ? $pos : 0;
        $x[$i] = $chars[$pos];
        if ($pos > 0) break;
        if (!$loop && !$i && !$pos) $x = $chars[1] . $x;
    }
    return $x;
}
```